# Why does following code starts misbehaving if mouse is clicked few times?

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

Problem:
Following is a qt qml program. I am using qt6 version.
on repeated mouse clicks, program starts behaving incorrectly.
The rotation on each start after mouse is clicked,
goes on with reduced speed. What is causing bug in
this code, which seems perfect to me.

Following is a qt qml program. I am using qt6 version. on repeated mouse clicks, program starts behaving incorrectly. The rotation on each start after mouse is clicked, goes on with reduced speed. What is causing bug in this code, which seems perfect to me.

```
import QtQuick

Window {
    width: Screen.width
    height: Screen.height
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Firki")    
    property int globalFrom: 0

    Image {
        anchors.fill: parent
        source: "qrc:/images/background.png"

        Image {
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            height: parent.height / 2
            source: "qrc:/images/pole.png"
        }

        Image {
            id: firki
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            source: "qrc:/images/pinwheel.png"

            RotationAnimation on rotation {
                id: rotatefirki
                loops: rotateblurredfirki.loops
                duration: rotateblurredfirki.duration
                from: rotateblurredfirki.from
                to: rotateblurredfirki.to
                running: rotateblurredfirki.running
            }
        }

        Image {
            id: blurredfirki
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            source: "qrc:/images/blur.png"
            opacity: 0

            RotationAnimation on rotation {
                id: rotateblurredfirki
                loops: Animation.Infinite
                duration: 1000
                from: globalFrom
                to: 360
                running: false
            }
        }
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent

        onClicked: {
            if(!rotateblurredfirki.running)
            {
                rotateblurredfirki.restart()
                blurredfirki.opacity = 1
            }
            else
            {
                rotateblurredfirki.stop()
                globalFrom = Math.floor(blurredfirki.rotation)
                blurredfirki.opacity = 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the `paused` property will be useful to you here. First bind rotatefirki's paused property to rotateblurredfirki's.

```
    RotationAnimation on rotation {
        id: rotatefirki
        ...
        paused: rotateblurredfirki.paused
    }
```

Then change your mouse click handler to toggle the paused the property:

```
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent

        onClicked: {
            if(!rotateblurredfirki.running)
            {
                // Not running, so start the animation
                rotateblurredfirki.restart()
            }
            else
            {
                // Keep it running, but pause it
                rotateblurredfirki.paused = !rotateblurredfirki.paused
                blurredfirki.opacity = 1 - blurredfirki.opacity
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you @JarMan. But what causes the problem if I use start() and stop() instead of restart() and pause(). Does it cause multiple instances of Rotation instantiated ?

Comment: No, it doesn't create multiple instances of Rotation. I assume it restarts the animation with the full 1000ms duration but with a shorter distance to travel, so it appears to move slower. If you're using a linear animation, you might be able to fix your code by just adjusting the duration each time too, but since you want it to loop, you also need to reset the `from` and the `duration` when it gets back to 0. So it becomes a mess. Pausing instead of stopping keeps it much simpler.